# How to insert into a table when a button is clicked?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form to get the employee details like employee id, name etc. I have another table that contains services that the employee can perform. When I create a new employee I need to select service they can perform.

Table structure for employee is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
  `emp_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_first_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_last_name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_emergency_contact` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `emp_id_card` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_time_in` time NOT NULL,
  `emp_time_out` time NOT NULL,
  `emp_date_of_hire` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_date_of_termination` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_date_of_rehire` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `emp_reference_number` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_service_limitation` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `emp_chair_renter` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_certificates` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=243867 ;
```

Another table service is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `service_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `service_tax` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `service_length` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `service_price` double NOT NULL,
  `manufacture_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I click the add service button I need to insert the employee id and service id into another table addservice, with employee_id and service_id. I have a separate controller, model and view for employee and service separately. When I enter the employee details I need to insert both service and employee id.

Can some on help me code a model, controller and view. My view file where I click the service is:

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="header">Service id</th>
                    <th class="yellow header headerSortDown">Service name </th>
                    <th class="green header">Service catogary</th>
                    <th class="red header">Service tax</th>
                    <th class="red header">Service length</th>
                    <th class="red header">Service price</th>
                    <th class="red header">Actions</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                  foreach($service as $row)
                  {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['service_name'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['service_tax'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['service_length'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['service_price'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td class="crud-actions">
                      <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/selected/add/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">Add service</a>  

</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
 ?>      
</tbody>
</table>
<a href='admin/employee/add' class="btn btn-info">Continue as chair renter</a> 
              <?php echo '<div class="pagination">'.$this->pagination->create_links().'</div>'; ?>
```

I have no idea how to write a code for controller and model.
my model page

```
class selected extends CI_Model
{
 function store_service($data)
    {
        $insert = $this->db->insert('service', $data);
        return $insert;
    }
}
```

my controller

```
class Admin_employee extends CI_Controller {
 public function add()
    {


                $data_to_store = array(
                'id' => $this->input->post('id'),

                );
                //if the insert has returned true then we show the flash message
                if($this->addservice_model->store_addservice($data_to_store)){
                    $data['flash_message'] = TRUE; 
                }else{
                    $data['flash_message'] = FALSE; 
                }

            }

        }

        //load the view
        $data['main_content'] = 'admin/addservice/add';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
    }       

}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far to achieve it ?

Comment: i tried to get the employee id using session $this->session->set_userdata('tax_details', ['total'=>$this->input->post('id')) and i passed the service id when a button is clicked using the function  $data_to_store = array(
    'id' => $this->uri->segment(4),
                   
                );

Comment: What is the problem in it ?

Comment: i dont know how to put the employee id and service id together in a table when a button is presed.only when the button is presed i can get the service id

Comment: Can you show your controller , model and view that you have. (Even if that is initial stage that's ok).

Comment: i have edited my question where i have my view

Comment: where is form?? and you need to submit data from from and show it on table?? is it??

Comment: that is the view where i list the service i have and i get the employee detail in a separate controller and model

Comment: So, You know about listing the users and you wanted to do the inserting Isn't it ?

Comment: i have written this function in the mean while is this right.in controller..public function add()
 {
 $this->load->library('session');
 
 $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
 $data_to_store = array('employee_id'=>$taxdetail['total'],
 'service_id'=>$id);
 $this->selected_model->store_employee($data_to_store);
      $data['main_content'] = 'admin/selected/list';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);  
 
 }

Comment: in model file  function store_employee($data)
    {
  $insert = $this->db->insert('addservice', $data);
     return $insert;
 }

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question you want to add Employee details and add services by selecting them from table.For this you have can call function on click event of add button store value in hidden field.

```
<button onClick="add_service(this,<?php echo $row['id'];?>)">Add</button>

<input id="service_ids" name="service_ids" type="hidden">
```

javascript:

```
  <script>
    function add_service(clicked_button,service_id)
    {
    $(clicked_button).attr('disabled','disabled');

if($("#service_ids").val()=="")
{
$("#service_ids").val(service_id);
}
else
{
var serviceids=$("#service_ids").val()+','+service_id;
$("#service_ids").val(serviceids);
}
}
   </script>
```

Now when you post form you can get employee details and service ids as comma separated string.
After insertion in of employee use `$insertid=$this->db->insert_id(); to last insert id which will be your current employee id.

Use PHP explode function to extract them as array.Now loop through this array and you will get service ids.

Comment: i dont want to input service id. when i press the add service button i need to insert the service id and employe id in the add service table

Comment: <a href="'.site_url("admin").'/selected/add/'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-info">Add service</a>  
 this is where i get my service id and somewhere before i get my employee id

Comment: somewhere before means in another view??

Comment: yes i first get my employee id in a separate view and select service for the employee where the service is in separate view for that service view i get the service id and insert both service and employee id

Comment: if that is the situation you can just add employee id in end of href url as `<a href="site_url("admin").'/selected/add/'.$row['id'].'/'.$employee_id" class="btn btn-info">Add service</a>` and use $this->uri->segment(5) to get employee id

Comment: but there i need to pass the service id to the add function

Comment: i am not getting the point.`$row['id']` is service id i.e.`$this->uri->segment(4)` and employee_id is `$this->uri->segment(5)`

Comment: i think he want to add the services while he is creating a new employee. in that moment, when he is adding the services to the employee in his view, the employee itself is not created yet in the database.. so he dont know which employee id to add to the relation table (employee_id/service_id) since it still doesnt exist (it ll be created via auto_increment when the employee is added to databse). if i also understand this completly wrong, then sorry :D the question is just confusing :)